# How to hide grid lines in barchart?

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am creating a *JR* report with an bar chart.

Everything shows up fine but I am not able to hide the gridlines on the chart.

I am using *JFreeChart 1.0.12* and *JasperReports 4.6*

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802773/lines

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802773/grid

Comment: Have you tried `set(Domain|Range)GridlinesVisible(false)`? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that your current approach.

Comment: @user1625419 Could you tell me how can I also use JfreeCharts with JasperReports server? I have tried but couldn't.